# Drive yelling AE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: sata

I have a drive that throws this kind of messages. I'm running 16.04.2 amd64 with the hwe kernel.

I'm searched a bit and I'm not sure what to understand here. Some people are saying that this is not a drive issue, some other are. How can I check that my drive is in a good state for sure considering this error?

```
[31919.519017] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x200 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[31919.519036] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[31919.519048] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[31919.519058] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[31919.519069] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:48:50:fc:70/01:00:08:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 
131072 out
                    res 40/00:48:50:fc:70/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[31919.519095] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[31919.519104] ata4: hard resetting link
[31919.861466] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[31919.861975] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
[31919.862009] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed         [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF] (Node ffff8d12be536e88), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
[31919.862241] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
[31919.862259] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF] (Node ffff8d12be536e88), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
[31919.862331] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[31919.862338] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdl] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[31919.862339] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdl] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[31919.862340] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdl] tag#9 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[31919.862341] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdl] tag#9 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 08 70 fc 50 00 01 00 00
[31919.862341] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdl, sector 141622352
[31919.862361] ata4: EH complete
```

Comment: It not filling that fast I receive this message kind of 5 times a day

Comment: Is the unaligned write command linked to the ACPI error ? because the guy in the like don't have those unaligned write messages